# UITableView, запомнить положение скрола

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Как запомнить положение внутри UITableView и восстановить эти координаты при следующем возврате на контроллер с UITableView?

Comment: Я так понимаю ответ ниже не подошел? Дайте что ли больше контекста тогда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView это наследник UIScrollView. Т.е. ему доступны все методы и свойства UIScrollView.
Запоминаем позицию:

```
CGPoint contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
```

Возвращаемся на позицию(с анимацией или без):

```
[tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: При попытке конвертации в NSValue для последующего сохранения в NSUserDefaults, ругается "Attempt to set a non-property-list object NSPoint: {0, 162.333} as an NSuSerDefaults value for key coord".
Как правильно хранить и восстанавливать позицию экрана в userdefaults?

Comment: @Chekist, NSStringFromCGPoint и CGPointFromString в помощь:) И не забывайте отмечать ответ как верный, если он вам подошел или дайте фидбек почему ответ не подошел